# How can i find old user and new user? . Application already on store and no login functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

My ios Application already on store. I dont have login/Signup functionality.

What i want to do is I want to add some functionality in new build but that should not affect/can't use by old user. Only new installed user (new user) can use that.

I dont have any server/API which can tell this is old user.

Is there any way which can tell person have just install application and not using already.

Comment: Do you save somewhere in NSUserDefaults or KeyChain some value?

Comment: no. I dont have any specific value. I need other way.

Comment: Can we check application is updating ?

Comment: I have database for store my data. From that I can find out. Thank you. I got my way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have API/Server but for this application I use DB. From which I Can get Date and It's Solved.

Any Person can solve this issue with help of DB/API/Server.

All application mostly have one of thing. So Person can Achieve. Yes if you planing for new launch you can put version tracker, but for old app you can use this solution.

Thank you. 
SmartbeRRRY.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No, you cannot achieve what you wish.

Longer Answer:

You can come up with heuristics to approximate the answer, but without an external record you can never be 100% sure, even if you had planned for this scenario in advance. Consider how a "new user" would be defined. If someone uses the app, then eradicates all evidence of it from a system (say by restoring from a backup from prior to when the app was first installed), and finally installs the latest version are they a "new user"?

As to possible heuristics, maybe look at the creation date of the app's Documents folder (which is inside the App's container). Containers are not (normally?) re-created on app update, so comparing that creation date to the release dates of your app's version will give you a guesstimate at which version was first install on the current device/OS install.

So unless someone comes up with something obscure to solve your problem, which logic suggests is not likely, you'll probably be better off reviewing your model so you don't require this information.

HTH

Comment: I have DB which will solve my problem. From db Data i can find out.

Comment: @Smartberrry - if your db is external (off-device) then that is probably your answer, if it's on-device and could be effected by app uninstall/reinstall then it's not 100% but might be good enough for your needs. So sounds like you have a solution.